# Who pays funds for Marketing, Giveaways for Decentralized Company like Binance?

Tags: contract-development, dapps, smart-contract-wallets, decentralized-exchange, binance-smart-chain

I wonder who gives funds for Marketing, Community Giveaways, etc in a decentralized companies like Binance. For Example, right now "Press a Button, Win a Bitcoin!" Event is going and the winner is going to get 1 BTC, But who gives that 1 BTC in a decentralized platform. Do we have any Smart Contract functions to allocate the funds for these type of Marketing, Give away activities? If so, Who calls that function and How is Binance going to be Decentralized in a way one controls the funds for this type of activities?

Answer (score 0):

First, Binance is not a decentralized exchange but rather a centralized exchange just like Coinbase, FTX, etc. So Binance of course has a budget to pay for all their marketing efforts from maybe the transaction fee they charge (given they are the leading exchange in volume) or from selling the BNB coins they hold from their sponsored chain BNB-chain (It is a different entity from Binance Exchange).